Editing a question to make it more general (e.g. Java ArrayList -> List)
I noticed that How to zip two Java Lists was originally written specifically about Java ArrayList, and then about 2.5 years later, the question was edited to make it more generic about the Java List class which ArrayList implements.



That threw me off a bit, since changing the question (even if slightly) from what was originally asked seems a bit contrary to the usual practice on Stack Overflow.
For this specific question, most solutions that apply to ArrayList would also apply to any random access List.  Though some of the solutions are only applicable to List implementations that are random access (e.g. not LinkedList), and would have terrible performance on other List implementations.  There are other qualities about ArrayList that could be utilized in an answer (but currently aren't), such as its mutability.
The more general question certainly serves as a better question overall from a knowledge repository standpoint, since the general solution is usually what should be used.  And many of the times that I've seen questions about ArrayList specifically (including, frankly, this one), there wasn't a great reason that they should have been asked in that manner in the first place, and probably should have been more general about List.
How does the community feel about editing a question to make it more general like this?

OK, I agree that changing ArrayList -> List means that some of the answers might become less applicable. However, on the other hand, the other option would be would one question per list implementation. Is that really optimal? A large portion of the possible solutions would overlap. Say, if you want to just iterate through both list via iterator (or a for-each loop which uses it). I think that one question that collects all solutions, including special solutions for different list implementations, as well as general solutions would be more useful for a library.

Related: Should questions receiving a general answer edit with a more general title?; What to do about questions that are much more general and timeless than their tags or titles?

regardless of my answer, i don't think editing it again to undo the change makes since in specific cases like this that have existed with the change for 6 years.

In this specific case, I'd favor either editing the question back or editing the answers that only apply to random-access lists (such as the top answer) to specify that caveat.  Probably the latter.

It should be a case by case basis. Not every question should be edited to the more generic form that thousands of questions can be dupe closed to.
It's important to keep questions such that people who are looking for a specific solution can find it. If the question is edited to be so generic that it does a poor job at answering a broader selection of questions when it was already doing a great job of answering a narrow selection... it hasn't been improved... all we've done is create a bucket to throw trash in.

IIRC there was a policy post on this, pushing against broad catch-all canonicals that aren't useful.

Case by case indeed, and it's a lot to do with what people would be searching for I'd reckon. In this specific case I find it a very good edit, but for simpler questions that cover the basics of lists, I'd think that having the word ArrayList in there , being the most often used implementation of a List in the wonderful world of Java , can actually benefit. Because that is what people who don't know collection classes from memory through experience and refuse to read the documentation will be searching for.

I really do not see the point in modifying the question of the original author so heavily here.
In my eyes, the better option is to provide a generic answer explicitly stating that it not only applies to ArrayLists, but to all Java Lists. This answer could also incorporate the modified examples from the edit.

If I search for how to do something with Lists, I'd avoid Q&As specifically about ArrayLists. It's not like I'd never visit the results for a subset of the problem - I'd do it if I don't find enough resources for the general thing I want, in order to try and generalise from there.
